# Why connectionstring without metadata works?

Tags: entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I had connection strings for entity framework edmx, which is usual EF connection string with metadata.

Now i am implementing mvc-mini-profiler and wrote method below to create context. I am using just sql connection string part now, no longer using EF connection string.

**Now it works but i am curious how it is getting metadata(.csdl, .ssdl address), If it can find now then why 'new Context()' need metadata**

```
public static T GetProfiledContext<T>() where T : ObjectContext
    {
        // create connection
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
        // wrap the connection with a profiling connection that tracks timings 
        var profiledDbConnection = MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);
        // create context
        return profiledDbConnection.CreateObjectContext<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it works without metadata is that `CreateObjectContext` extension method will add these metadata when creating the context. It uses wildcards: `res://*/` to get metadata. You can check the implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/Data/ContextUtils.cs).